# Set S of n numbers - have a subset with the probability of each element of S occuring in it equal

Tags: algorithm, set

I have this problem

> You are given a set S of n numbers. You must pick a subset S′ of k numbers from S such that the probability of each element of S occurring in S′ is equal (i.e., each is selected with probability k/n). You may make only one pass over the numbers. What if n is unknown?

and I even have a solution: http://www.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.43

Still: I **don't understand the problem text at all**.

I'm given a set S of n numbers. Fine. I need to pick a subset (2^n subsets are possible) of k numbers such that the probability of each element of S occurring in S' is equal... the obvious answer to me would be to just grab the empty S' set: each element in S would have 0 probability to be in S'.

If this is not acceptable (and it should have been stated), I suppose I should count for the most-recurring element (appearing T times) in S and make every other element have exactly T instances in S' (it should still be a subset if the elements are contained in S).

I don't really understand the priority queue solution, nor the k/n probability. Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: When they say each element needs an equal probability, they mean each element is distinct. Even if you had the set `{1, 2, 2, 3}`, the two `2`s are separate elements that happen to look the same, but aren't. Your paragraph about `T instances` is headed in the wrong direction because you're thinking of those `2`s as the same element. For simplicity, imagine a programmer's set, where elements can occur only once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very famous problem with a resulting technique called [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) - a very useful algorithm for stream processing of big data. The preceding link can give you the precise setting, motivation, and explanation of the solution.

Comment: Interesting, thanks Ami! One question though: does the alogorithm in the wikipedia page also work for k = 1 i.e. one element only in the subset S'? At first I'd say that the more I proceed forward in the stream, the less likely is that a successor gets chosen to replace the unique chosen number

Comment: Yes, it works for k=1. The more you proceed down the stream: a. a new element is less likely to be selected, but b. if it is selected, it has fewer chances of getting evicted. Happily - poof - the math works out that the position in the stream doesn't matter. Isn't it great? I love this simple algorithm.